# Cache Control Private Usage in HTTPS

Tags: http, https, cache-control

I am looking at HTTP Cache Control Mechanism, and have a question on `cache-control: private`.

Here is the W3C specification on `private` cache control.

> private
>
> Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache. This allows an origin server to state that the specified parts of the
> response are intended for only one user and are not a valid response for requests by other users. A private (non-shared) cache MAY cache the response.
> Note: This usage of the word private only controls where the response may be cached, and cannot ensure the privacy of the message content.
>
> Source: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1

which seems to disable caching on all the servers in the middle, e.g. by ISP Server.
However, as we all know that HTTPS have encrypted its content, path and even header, So intermediate servers should not be able to cache the content meaningfully.

So is there any real usage / difference when I add `cache-control: private` to Https Header?
Or will the browser or any Https client when visit the same page have any different behavior? Will there be any edge cases where having `cache-control: private` to a Https request does make a difference?

I know for sure `cache-control: private` is useful in Http, but is it useful in Https?

Comment: Yes, a proxy that passes on, rather than terminates, HTTPS traffic cannot do any caching (or even see the cache headers). However, some caching architectures (like Cloudflare and other edge caches) do terminate the HTTPS connection before making a separate request to the origin server. And `private` is meaningful to these servers.

Comment: Do you mean some middle servers, may convert Https to Http request and forward the header to the destination. Therefore if no private header is placed, then all other servers behind the middle servers may cache the request?

Comment: It needn't be HTTP rather than HTTPS, the point is just that it's a separate connection to the origin server. The client connects to Cloudflare (for example), which decides whether to serve something from its cache or make a new connection to the origin server to get a fresh copy. It will respect the cache headers coming from the origin server, so in this case `private` is still useful despite using HTTPS for all connections.